# Replacing stock dialer app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, phone-app

I've a rooted Samsung Galaxy S3 device, and I don't like the stock dialer app; can I replace (i.e. remove it totally) it with another dailer without breaking the phone functionality?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it completely?

Comment: You could download a different dialler and just use that as default, but the 'In Call' screen will remain Samsung's one. The other alternative is rooting the phone, finding a dialler replacement zip with a script that will correctly install and replace the dialler, pray it reboots, and then hope it doesn't crash out. I flash diallers a fair bit and the majority of the time they don't work, with the exception of flashing the KitKat dialler on a Google Edition ROM on the S4 where the dialler is provided by the ROM developer directly for that one ROM, but never over Touchwiz.