# Is incoming/outgoing call screen customizable?

Tags: applications, calls

I'm looking for a way to change the incoming/outgoing call screen (that of my Sony phone needs replacement at least because when I press a button to turn on the screen and tap the "end call" button or to see the length of the talk, the screen is turned off in a second). I've tried a couple of dialer/contacts apps and those don't actually change that screen. Moreover, the comment [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82343/replacing-stock-dialer-app) suggests that this screen may be changed only on a rooted device.

Is it so? Is this screen a part of launcher? A separate app? Is rooting required to change this? Where can I grab alternative implementations? A more detailed how to is appreciated since the phone is rooted already anyway.

PS the screen I'm talking about looks similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=v.d.d.answercall) app

Comment: @Abochur yeap, I've tried this one, a nice customizable dialer, but it doesn't change the screen I'm talking about (or at least I haven't found the option to do so)

Answer (score 2):

To do so. Root the phone. Extract, and recompile these apps:

```
/system/priv-app/TelephonyProvider/TelephonyProvider.apk
/system/priv-app/Telecom/Telecom.apk
/system/app/InCallUiNext/InCallUiNext.apk
/system/app/telresources/telresources.apk
/system/framework/framework-res.apk
```

And this file also:

```
/system/framework/telephony-common.jar
```

After changing their drawable elements, return them where they were and set these permissions.

`chmod 0755` for folders
`chmod 0644` for files

This will work very well for you but always keep a backup of them incase something goes wrong. This is for editing the app but if the dialer is freezing after ending a call, then what you need to do is:

```
 1. Open Settings
 2. Click Apps
 3. Press the options icon
 4. Tap Show System
 5. Clear Data and Cache for Dialer and Telephony Provider
```

If still this doesn't work if you have TWRP Recovery installed:

```
 1. Press Wipe
 2. Advanced Wipe
 3. Check Dalvik Cache and Cache partitions
 4. Swipe to clear them
 5. Reboot System
```

**Note: The in-call popup never changes no matter what dialer you opt for. Deleting it for example means the Telephone Service is tampered with. And you won't receive any calls. All other apps can offer adress book, blocking and dialer but on call dialing is then commanded to Telecom app which then manages the calling services and renders UI for call until the end. It offers the native service that is for calling and communicating to the phone gsm radio. All other apps can't do this. Just like in a media player, a media decoding library or a codec, so is the Telecom app essence and purpose. It is the core handler of telephony. Unless you modify it or redevelop it by code. It's one of the essential apps alongside SystemUI and Framework. That's why it won't be a walk in the park replacing it. It is integral to many system apps**

This will solve your issue very well. Please let me know if it helped you

Comment: Wow, this looks very helpful except that for recompiling I have to get code of those screens somewhere. Any ideas (aside coding those from scratch)?

Comment: @YakovL Coding from scratch needs one to be very cautious. For your information, modifying will only change parameters and a few resources from the app hence you don't need to take care of the application's native libs in /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64 etc. That will make an easy go. But back to recompile from scratch. If your device is marshmallow or nougat, for example you need to understand that SDK at large, Java for developing android apps, Java for those framework files and writing libraries to support your current device platform. Remember libraries

Comment: are based on processor of device. We have, armeabi, arm64, arm and a few more. The once listed are for example cordial to the Mediatek chip. Since we have, Spreadtrum, Mediatek, Qualcomm, Broadcom, Samsung, Intel, and more processors too you need to take care of this too. So this needs a lot of knowledge about hardware and firmware at large. I haven't mentioned about network too which affects the type of Kernel and processor of device. 4g based processors and kernels, 3g and 2g based processors and kernels too exist. So what I mean developing a native app and is cordinating apps needs total

Comment: digging about the firmware you're running which is rather not an easy business. That's why I suggested only recompilation. I'm not trying to show you how hard it is. One can make it but through a lot of software testing and fixing since you are not your phone's dev.

Comment: Ok, let's make this straight: is changing that screen can only be done by some coding or I can find one somewhere like I find another dialer at Google Play and install it (may be with installation requiring some extra root procedures)?

Comment: @YakovL Yeah. Read the re-edit of the answer.

Comment: Right, thanks. How do you know which APKs to edit? I found only `/system/framework/framework-res.apk` and `/system/framework/telephony-common.jar` on my Sony device, with first 4 files missing. ("show hidden files" is enabled in my Root browser)

Comment: When you go to settings apps, what is the name of your default dialer. This will be the name of it even in system priv-app. Alternatively if you're unable to identify them. Download Terminal app and run this command: ls /system/app and send me the names of all files listed there. run again: ls /system/priv-app and send me the names of all files shown and I shall identify the apps responsible for calling if incase they have different names on your device brand. That way I'll be able to tell you which apps to recompile